# Python - subprocess dying causes program to be suspended

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, ros

I am invoking a subprocess via some Python code resembling the following:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-ic", ". foo.bash && some_func_from_foo"])
```

One of the processes I am opening spawns a bunch of child process (or subprocesses, or forked processes, not sure which), and *one* of the child processes dies. This dying is OK and expected behavior. However, I do *not* expect the actual Python program to be interrupted when this node dies, but right after the child process dies the Python program is suspended and I see `[1]+  Stopped                 rosrun my_package my_app.py`.

Some more details: I am running a ROS launch file from the command line. When one of its nodes dies it gives the following sort of output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  ...
[my_node_name] process has died [pid 30816, exit code -6, ...]
```

And then the Python program gets sent to the background, putting me back in bash (I have to run `fg 1` to resume the Python program).

Is there any way to prevent the Python process from getting backgrounded by a subprocess that spawns a child that dies?

Comment: Something is stopping the `rosrun` process I think, not your python script (since `rosrun` is running your python script, no?). What might be signalling that process?

Comment: Hmm, indeed, `rosrun` is running the script, I'm not running it directly. I guess what must be happening in that case is that the `roslaunch` command is messing with `rosrun`, which I could see happening but am not sure why. I'll have to go post over on http://answers.ros.org.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess` [may thrown an exception](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#exceptions). Have you tried wrapping your code in a try except block to deal with the errors?

Comment: Why would an exception put the script in the background instead of killing it?

Comment: The line `subprocess.Popen` executes immediately and successfully as it just opens the script the background, so where would I put the try/except block?